# Remove special characters Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string which looks like this and I don't know what to use to clean it. I know that it is `'`. I don't want to use `strreplace`.

`My string&#39;`

Comment: You can use decodeURI() if your string is encoded. Else please provide more details about your string

Comment: @MonikaMangal this is not URI encoding

Comment: can you share your string pleas.

Answer (score 0):

Please check meta utf-8 in html5 document

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Browser will convert special characters in to required utf-8

Comment: It has that in head. This particular data is being loaded asynchronous. Can that be the problem?

Comment: @Ciprian, are you any database? mysql/oracle?

Comment: No. It's a nosql database.